Is there any difference in security between UserManager.FindByEmail and UserManager.Users.SingleOrDefault?
Initially I was using:
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);  

and now I'm using:
var normalizedEmail = _userManager.NormalizeEmail(loginDto.Email);
var user = await _userManager.Users
      .Include(p => p.TokensPoints)
      .Include(p => p.UserRoles)
          .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.NormalizedEmail == normalizedEmail);

In terms of security for logging into a user account like this:
var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false);

Is there any difference between the two calls to fetch the user? Pro's vs Con's

I assume the goal of the UserManager is to hide the implementation of the datamodel by means of offering methods for a specific purpose without the need for callers to know or access the data directly. Having an public interface that allows you to do both is a bit of a bummer.

The .NET source code is available to everyone. Take a look at it and see what it does in the first case.

since the password would have to have been input by the user, CheckPassword is certainly more secure.  (it's unclear where email is coming from, but I'm assuming those are from validated claims which are only session-based... less secure as session could be stolen... if the claims aren't validated even less secure)

Email is coming from a login form client side. As you can see I normalize it first, the I fetch the User. Once I have it I login. Overall, I'd just like to know if there is some special secret sauce being used to fetch the user with FindByEmailAsync or if what I'm doing now is sufficient and doesn't pose any security risks?

sry, I misunderstood there.  You're always calling CheckPassword... not sure there's any security implications between the two there... but if you use SingleOrDefault you might want to try/catch.  (findby or firstofdefault will be quicker as Single throws when more than 1 found... searches for all instances) Be sure that e-mail is guaranteed to be unique.  Also check for nulls.  On security side what you return and when is important.  (don't reveal "this e-mail doesn't exist, or password for e-mail is incorrect")  Response time should be equal for all cases, logged-in vs failed to login.

The UserManager.FindByEmailAsync method is part of the UserManager class. Its implementation depends on the IUserEmailStore interface. It can find users by email, but it is limited to querying simple information of users. It does not involve querying related tables, and the query speed is fast.
Source code example: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1286
SingleOrDefaultAsync is a LINQ extension method for asynchronous query. It is used to return the only element that meets the specified conditions from a sequence. If the sequence is empty, it returns the default value; if there are multiple elements in the sequence, an exception is thrown. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.singleordefaultasync?view=efcore-8.0
This method allows you to query users through LINQ, include related navigation properties, and load data from related tables. SingleOrDefaultAsync is relatively more flexible and allows loading related data, but you need to be careful to validate the email parameter to prevent SQL injection attacks.
The CheckPasswordSignInAsync method is part of the SignInManager class and is used to verify the user's password and attempt to log in. . From the source code, we can see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L374 that it not only checks the password, but also handles the lock logic after a failed login.
